# Do any keyboard shortcuts work on Azure Data Studio on macOS?

Tags: azure-data-studio

The [microsoft ADS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-ver16) say F5 is "Run".

[image]

It does nothing on my macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the shortcut to some other key rather than the default f5. Try changing it to command+k (⌘ + k).